# error: G_TEST_SUBPROCESS_DEFAULT undeclared when building gtkmm-4.0

Tags: gtkmm, gtk4

I was trying to install gtkmm-4.0 and since my distro only ships gtkmm-3.0 I decided to build myself.

Installed all the dependencies from the official gtkmm installation website and gave it a go.

meson setup succeeded. But ninja failed with this error

```
error: ‘G_TEST_SUBPROCESS_DEFAULT’ undeclared
```

Tried searching this up but found literally 0 results.
This looks like a glib include fail, since this macro is defined in the glib-2.0.

Any help could be appreciated.